# is it possible to use sympy to listlineplot

Tags: python, sympy

Here I have an Array

```py
Array(len(factor_list(x**j - 1)[1]) for j in range(1,200))
```

And I want to achieve the effect of

[image]

Which is to say,how to  plot all thses points and join them with lines.

```py
list(zip(range(1,20),
Array(len(factor_list(x**j - 1)[1]) for j in range(1,20))
   ))
```

I read the document of sympy, but I don't find what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy's plotting is rather limited for this type of plotting. As the intent is to only plot numbers, standard matplotlib comes in handy:

```py
from sympy import factor_list
from sympy.abc import x
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

indices = range(1, 200)
a = [len(factor_list(x ** j - 1)[1]) for j in indices]
plt.plot(indices, a)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: If your data is in a sympy `Array`, it needs to converted to a `list` before plotting: `plt.plot(indices, list(a))`.